# Multithreading in c# Monitor class

Tags: c#, multithreading

Why do i get the output 1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 when i use value as lokalvar and 
the correct ouput 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 when "value" is membervar?

i cant figure out why this happens. Thanks for any explanantions ;)

```
class Beispiel_3
{

int value = 0;

public void Execute_Threads()
{
// why is the out put wrong when i ise the varibale "value" here?
//===============================================================
    while (true)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(this);

        value++;
        if (value > 20)
            break;
        Console.WriteLine("Zahl = {0}  | Thread = {1}", value, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().ToString());
        Monitor.Exit(this);

    }

}
public void Execute_MainThread()
{
    Thread thread1, thread2;
    thread1 = new Thread(Execute_Threads);
    thread2 = new Thread(Execute_Threads);
    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Beispiel_3 bsp3 = new Beispiel_3();
    bsp3.Execute_MainThread();

}
```

Comment: What are "lokalvar" and "membervar"?

Comment: Also, how do you get an output of `1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ` when your only output statement is `Console.WriteLine("Zahl = {0}  | Thread = {1}", value, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().ToString());`

Comment: I just checked the output to understand. I changed Console.WriteLine(""); But what if the varibale "value" is declared at the position of the commant

Answer (score 0):

You have one class `Beispiel_3` in which you start two threads. If you declare `value` as a member of class `Beispiel_3` both threads use this one `value` and increase it more or less by turns. If you declare it in your method `Execute_Threads` each thread has its own variable `value` and always increase only his own variable `value`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did not know that. appreciate:)